# Horizontal scrolling not working in Windows 7 running on MBP using Boot Camp

Tags: macbook-pro, boot-camp, scrolling

Is there a way to enable horizontal scrolling on Windows installed on a bootcamp partition of MBP 13" Core 2 Duo, using a trackpad?

I had a look into the Boot Camp Control panel settings, but could not find a setting that suggested this.

I used the Boot Camp drivers that came with the MBP in the Mac OS X Install disk.

The vertical scroll is working fine, and the horizontal scroll works fine in the Mac world of things, so the hardware is fine.

I think maybe there might be an additional install for a driver that we may have to install? Or any update?

Comment: What version of boot camp and osx?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Trackpad++ (http://trackpad.powerplan7.com/)? Several folks have said it helps add horizontal and a few other things under Windows 7. Unfortunately I am still stuck on XP so I have not been able to try it myself.

Also, are there specific apps you want it for? Many have have workarounds for working with vertical scrolling (in IntelliJ IDEA you can hold down shift for instance).